# How to collect core dump files in Juniper ERX

Tags: juniper, troubleshooting, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

For troubleshooting purposes, I need to collect some files from my ERX.(by ftp)
Below is the content of my directory

```
ERX#dir

*** Active/standby file systems are being synchronized. ***

                                                               unshared
                      file                           size        size
------------------------------------------------   ---------   ---------
disk0:running.cnf                                     572514      572514
disk0:GE-HDE_0_07_21_2016_17_26.dmp                 38489957    38489957
disk0:GE-HDE_0_08_09_2016_16_41.dmp                 38674861    38674861
disk0:SRP-40G+_9_SC_08_09_2016_15_48.dmp           270021233   270021233
disk0:reboot.hty                                      119104      119104
disk0:srpioahotswap.log                                  336         336
disk0:system.log                                        1539        1539
disk0:hostkey2147483649.pub                              709         709
disk0:erx40_11-2-0.rel                             239432234   239432234
disk0:srp_stats.tsa                                   777391      777391
disk0:systemHalta7_210116_142344.tsa                  406816      406816
disk0:04102013.txt                                     18383       18383
standby-disk0:SRP-40G+_7_SC_08_09_2016_10_20.dmp      114688      114688
standby-disk0:SRP-40G+_7_SC_08_09_2016_15_49.dmp   211566592   211566592
standby-disk0:reboot.hty                               61696       61696
standby-disk0:srpioahotswap.log                          798         798
standby-disk0:system.log                                1279        1279
standby-disk0:systemHalta6_290715_141520.tsa          617924      617924
standby-disk0:systemHalta6_280516_170017.tsa          658452      658452
                                                          date           in
                      file                           (Africa/Douala)     use
------------------------------------------------   -------------------   ---
disk0:running.cnf                                  07/25/2012 09:25:20
disk0:GE-HDE_0_07_21_2016_17_26.dmp                07/21/2016 17:29:40
disk0:GE-HDE_0_08_09_2016_16_41.dmp                08/09/2016 16:45:32
disk0:SRP-40G+_9_SC_08_09_2016_15_48.dmp           08/09/2016 16:48:28
disk0:reboot.hty                                   08/09/2016 16:58:26
disk0:srpioahotswap.log                            08/09/2016 16:54:42
disk0:system.log                                   08/09/2016 16:55:24
disk0:hostkey2147483649.pub                        10/03/2011 05:57:24
disk0:erx40_11-2-0.rel                             08/27/2010 23:36:02    !
disk0:srp_stats.tsa                                01/12/2012 16:11:20
disk0:systemHalta7_210116_142344.tsa               01/21/2016 14:24:20
disk0:04102013.txt                                 10/04/2013 10:50:32
standby-disk0:SRP-40G+_7_SC_08_09_2016_10_20.dmp   08/09/2016 11:20:40
standby-disk0:SRP-40G+_7_SC_08_09_2016_15_49.dmp   08/09/2016 16:49:36
standby-disk0:reboot.hty                           08/09/2016 16:54:46
standby-disk0:srpioahotswap.log                    08/09/2016 16:54:48
standby-disk0:system.log                           01/21/2016 14:24:32
standby-disk0:systemHalta6_290715_141520.tsa       07/29/2015 14:16:10
standby-disk0:systemHalta6_280516_170017.tsa       05/28/2016 17:01:08
ERX#
```

The following outputs might be useful to you as well. 
My interest is the ***reboot.hty***  file

```
ERX#show version
Juniper Edge Routing Switch ERX-1440
Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Juniper Networks, Inc.  All rights reserved.
System Release: erx40_11-2-0.rel
        Version: 11.2.0 release-0.0 [BuildId 12329]   (July 12, 2010  12:35)
System running for: 0 days, 0 hours, 31 minutes, 50 seconds
        (since TUE AUG 09 2016 16:54:00 Africa/Douala)

slot  state      type       admin  spare running release   slot uptime
---- ------- ------------- ------- ----- ---------------- -------------
0    online  GE-HDE-8      enabled  ---  erx40_11-2-0.rel 0d00h:28m:25s
1    online  SERVICEMODULE enabled  ---  erx40_11-2-0.rel 0d00h:27m:27s
2      ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---
3      ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---
4      ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---
5      ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---
6    standby SRP-40G+      enabled  ---  erx40_11-2-0.rel      ---
7    online  SRP-40G+      enabled  ---  erx40_11-2-0.rel 0d00h:30m:07s
8      ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---
9      ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---
10     ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---
11     ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---
12     ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---
13     ---        ---        ---    ---        ---             ---

ERX#



ERX#sh host
        Static Host Table
        -----------------
   name        ip address     type
----------   --------------   ----
Typsoftftp   10.248.192.129   ftp

    NFS Host Table
    --------------
name   userid   groupid
----   ------   -------
    Clns Host Alias Table
    ---------------------
        area     system
name   address     ID     type
----   -------   ------   ----
ERX#
ERX#
ERX#ping 10.248.192.129
Sending 5 ICMP echoes to 10.248.192.129, timeout = 2 sec.
!!!!!
Success rate = 100% (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 9/10/15 ms
ERX#
```

Please, how do I proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can't you just use FTP or something to copy the files which interest you to a different host?

Comment: My concern is how to proceed by ftp in this particular case. In the past, I have done so with huawei's NE40, by inputting the loopback IP in the filezilla client and proceeding. but it doesn't seem to work in this case

Comment: in this case, the loopback IP of my ERX is 41.205.0.117, and from the "show host" output, I find the ftp server's IP in this case is 10.248.192.129

Comment: I'm not sure why you are concerned with the loopback address. @DatagramNetwork provided the answer.

Comment: Just seeing the answer. let me try and feedback

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may just push file to ftp server:

```
#copy /reboot.hty ftp://ftpuser:ftppasswd@IP_OF_FTP_SERVER/reboot.hty
```

Comment: Please, I don't seem to get it. if the user name is xxxx and the password is yyyy and the IP address is zzzz, how will that command be @Datagram

Comment: ftp://xxxx:yyyy@zzzz/reboot.hty

Comment: Does zzzz correspond to 10.248.192.129?

Comment: yes if it's your ftp server, ftp://username:password@10.248.192.129/reboot.hty

Comment: I get the following output `.................................................. (  1%)*  % Copy destination not valid`
'

Comment: Is there any more configuration I need to do on server side?  PS: Server is my PC and I use filezilla server

Comment: on server side ftp server need to listen on port and ideally firewall allow connection on port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43859/discussion-between-ntd-and-datagram-network).